# Is Android's source code buildable on El Capitan with XCode 7.2?

Tags: xcode, macos, makefile, gnu-make, android-build

I am trying to build AOSP's Lollipop-cts-dev branch on OSX El Capitan with MacOS SDK version 10.11. I faced different build issues with different settings. Currently I am getting below error:

```
system/core/include/log/log.h:35:20: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj32/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libinput_intermediates/Keyboard.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj32/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libinput_intermediates/InputDevice.o] Error 1
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj32/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libinput_intermediates/Input.o] Error 1
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

#### make failed to build some targets (03:58 (mm:ss)) ####
```

My guess is that it is because of incompatible version of OSX SDK for the AOSP code base. More specifically, as mentioned in the requirements
https://source.android.com/source/requirements.html
Android 5.x (Lollipop) requires Mac OS v10.8 (Mountain Lion).

Can someone confirm this? Is there no straightforward way to build Lollipop on El Capitan?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this helps, but you may find the following code in `build/core/combo/HOST_darwin-x86.mk`:

```
ifeq ($(mac_sdk_version),10.8)
host_toolchain_header := $(HOST_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT)/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin$(gcc_darwin_version)/4.2.1/include
HOST_GLOBAL_CFLAGS += -isystem $(host_toolchain_header)
endif
else
```

Modifying `10.8` to `10.11` may solve the problem.

Solution Source (written in Simplified Chinese):

http://www.liball.me/mac-10-10-build-android-4-4-4-for-nexus/